# Create a Scala function without explicitly declaring the types

Tags: scala

I'd like to create a simple function:

```
def sum(a,b) = a + b
```

But then it won't compile, I have to do

```
def sum(a:Int, b:Int) : Int = a + b
```

Which is much longer to code and type-bound. Is it possible to do it without specifying the type, just as I'd do in OCaml:

```
let sum x y = x + y
```

Comment: Scala is a statically typed language. How would you expect the compiler to infer the type of `a` and `b`? the `+` operator can be applied to any two types.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well, since it's statically typed, I would actually expect it to infer exactly that ;) Seriously, that this doesn't work is just an artifact of Scala's specific type system, while in other languages like Haskell, which infer polymorphic types, `sum a b = a + b` would get a type like `forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a`. This can be done because there we have no subtying and type classes are closed, which is both not the case in Scala.

Comment: @phg But how would type inference pick up that you're referring to two `Int`'s and not two `String`'s?

Comment: Well, OCaml is statically typed, and doesn't complain. It's just the same code which can be applied to many types

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov The point is that Haskell doesn't fix the concrete types at that point. The inferred type is fully polymorphic and can be applied to everything, as long as there exists an instance of the `Num` typeclass. In Scala terms, something like `sum[T](a: T, b: T)(implicit plusable: { def +(T, T): T })`. If you later happen to apply `sum` to an `Int`, then that's ok, because that's subsumed under the polymorphic type.

Comment: ... which of course wouldn't work well in Scala, for the reasons I named. I just mentioned it because I wanted to say that such inference is possible in principle.

Comment: @phg That's an interesting approach. I should definitely checkout how Haskell type system works.

Comment: [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley-Milner_type_system), mostly. Plus some awesome extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala, you can omit a function's *return* type, but not the argument types:

```
def sum(a:Int, b:Int) = a + b // return type inferred to be Int
```

For more about Scala type inference, see: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference.html